# what is the best way to inverse sort in python?

Tags: python, sorting

how can I use python to  `sort()` list by letters from Z to A?

```
names = ["Adam","Alex","Mariah","Martine","Columbus"]
```

*beginner

Answer (score 2):

By telling the [`sorted()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) or [`list.sort()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) to `reverse` the output:

```
sorted(names, reverse=True)  # returns new list
names.sort(reverse=True)     # sorts list in place
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to mark a question as duplicate and answer it at the same time?

Comment: @Sait: it is good practice to close a question as a duplicate once you are aware of there being a good duplicate target. I wasn't aware of the duplicate until River flagged it, or I would have duped it sooner.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oddly enough that got my flag disputed somehow...

Comment: @River actually that was because the post was also in the Triage queue and your flag was disputed when the last *Looks Good* vote came in. I'll probably report that as an issue.